# How to safely extract an encrypted zip folder to a random folder, load all extracted files into memory safely delete the extracted files

Tags: data-protection

I have an encrypted 7z file which has some binary data files.

- I am on windows platform (Windows 10 - Customers are also on same platform).
- I am using C++ 17.
- I am using a third party library (C standard) that can load these binary files only from disk (not from memory streams) into memory.
- Loading the bin files from disk to memory takes a few milliseconds.
- I don't want to let the users of my software to be able to read the content of the binary files.
- I can't use a online service to host these bin files because the customers should be able to use the software on a standalone computer without any network connectivity.

The way I am planning it now is as follows:

1. Choose a random folder path at runtime (in the windows temp folder)
2. Extract the encrypted 7z file to the above random path.
3. Immediately acquire a exclusive lock on the bin files using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex
4. Read the bin files
5. After the reading is done, overwrite the files with zeros
6. Delete the extracted files

Things that can go wrong in the above approach:

- Customers having admin privileges can potentially perfectly time the bin file loading in software and kill the process before the files are overwritten.
- Customers can potentially get a memory dump and read the data directly (not sure if this is so easy to pull off)
- Potentially more ways..

Is there any better way to deal with the situation?
Should I live with the potential of IP loss.